# Pandas DataFrame :Transforming integer categories for binary classification

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification

I have a pandas dataframe with 10 columns and I want to perform binary classification in such a way that SVC or any other classification algorithm can decide to which category a given intensity value belongs to.

```
mzmin  mzmax  rtmed rtmax   Sample 1  Sample 2
1045   1043   2368  2367       11920   11930
1048   1042   2361  2362       11920   11930
1045   1043   2368  2367       11920   11930
```

Currently, I can do regression with no worries but I don't know how to convert the above problem into a classification problem. How can I convert the columns `Sample 1` and `Sample 2` such that , when given an `intensity value`, `mzmin value`, or `mzmax value` e.t.c, it can output `sample 1` or `sample 2` as the response ?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to classify Sample 1 and Sample 2 from mzmin, rtmed e.t.c, those values can only help one conduct regression. I am sorry I really didnt understand your suggestion, would you be in a position to write it down in python code or pseudo -code or in some steps of some sort. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to convert your labels to 0/1 representing is sample 1 or is sample 2.

Comment: Do I need to use Label binarizer function                                                               `from sklearn import preprocessing                                                                                   `lb.fit( Sample1, Sample2)                                                                                                 `LabelBinirizer(neg_label = o, pos_label = 1,sparse_output = False) ?

Comment: @cosmosa , what would I do in the case with more than 2 samples ? and is the binarization only for the labels and not the actual values themselves ?

Comment: the columns sample1 and sample 2 always contain the same value. What you mean by predicting sample 1 or sample 2. could you explain it with an example?